# Re-Heat meringues after having them in the fridge for a long time?

Tags: food-safety, meringue

Three weeks ago I tried to make meringues. Unfortunately I left them in the oven for too short, and thus they were quite soft. Thus I put them in the fridge. Now I took them out again, and noticed that they were quite soft again (due to taking water). I put them now again in the oven (@100 °C for 3 hours). Are they still safe to eat, or should I throw them away?

Comment: Even if they're safe (which they might be), they're not going to be very nice after being kept in the fridge. Soft meringue can be good in some dishes but doesn't keep very well for texture. Hard meringue, including when it's crispy on the outside and softer inside spoils in the fridge by going soggy. It should be kept in an airtight container at room temperature. Even then recrisping in the oven might be a good idea.

Comment: @ChrisH, any reason you're posting this as comment instead of as an answer?

Comment: @Stephie it's close but lacking definitive information on how badly meringues don't keep in the fridge. Especially as I'm concentrating on the quality rather than the safety aspects and the latter may be affected by moisture absorption. Depending on how comments go and whether someone comes up with something better I might be able to turn it into an answer.